# How do I implement a raycast / laserpointer to Oculus controller?

Tags: virtual-reality, raycasting, oculus

I want to implement a graphic raycaster/ laserpointer to the left Oculus controller, so I can interact with UI buttons in Unity.

I have seen a lot of tutorials etc. but nothing has helped.

I want a laserbeam or laserpointer/graphic raycast to shoot out from Oculus controller when a button os pressed on the controller. I need the laserbeam to interact with UI buttons in Unity.

Comment: There is an official tutorial from Oculus on this topic under https://developer.oculus.com/blog/easy-controller-selection/ , which should provide you with a working example, even though it comes from Unity 5.X. Did you try this one already? If so, please explain what you don't understand or which part is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal raycast

I recomend you make this:

1. Create a script on your hand,and add a component called line renderer
2. In the script attach the lineRenderer component
3. make a simple raycast hit
4. get the position of the hit object
5. set the first position of the actual hand and the second to the hit object like this:

   `lineRenderer.SetPosition(0,transform.position);`
   `lineRenderer.SetPosition(1,hitObject.transform.position);`

And it draw a line from your hand to the hit object, remember to change the lineRender parameter to make a beautiful line

hope it helps

Comment: Sorry. It didnt. I tried creating a Gaze pointer to hit the UI buttons instead, and I followed two tutorials, but they didnt work. Do you know how to set a gaze pointer up? I have tried everything.

Comment: I made unity show the gaze pointer in front of me now! :) yay. The only thing is how I make it interact with the menu, and only the menu. The ring disappears sometimes, or "goes through" the menu canvas and buttons.

Comment: Try this: 1- Make a UI canvas in you face, show a small pointer in the middle of the UI always,and make a circle for the Gaze pointer that it can show/hide. 2-All of the element of the UI need to have a tag called UIElement. 3.-Make a raycast from your face to forward. 4.-Check the hit element you hit with raycast,and if his tag is UIElement make your Gaze pointer circle charge

Comment: The Canvas shows up in front of me in VR, and the gaze circle is in the middle. The elements should be UIElements as far as I can see.
The raycaster is on my playercontroller so it should go forward from there right? :) 
Is it possible to send personal messages in here? It would be easier. Or an email with pictures attached :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a project that uses unity's event system. It is a laser pointer which you can interact with unity's UI and 3d objects in the scene. If you want to check it out here's the link: https://github.com/balataca/oculus-laser-pointer